# Measure weekly average of a multiple netCDF files with NCO or Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, netcdf, nco

i have daily netcdf files from 2017 (365 'name_file.nc') and in my daily basics  i use to do some operations with NCO library and matlab.

I do the averages with matlab, but now i am searching how to do it with NCO or Python. (Actually i 
am going parallel so i'm in a migration process)

The main task is to read 7 .nc files (week) and do a new .nc file with the average values.

Some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of ideas; these operations are quite straighforward/easy with Python's NetCDF4/xarray/Numpy packages... But, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

NCO uses [ncra](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#xmp_ncra) for this. ncra can handle indexes or dates...see the examples, though it can be as simple as this one-liner:

```
ncra in[1-7].nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also treat the files as an ensemble and average them with CDO:

```
cdo ensmean in[1-7].nc out.nc
```

obviously you will need to put this in a loop in bash to cycle through the whole year.  Unfortunately there is not a built-in weekly average in CDO (only for hours, days, months and seasons), I think because weeks do not fit neatly in 365 days perhaps...  not sure.